# Angular Router's navigateByUrl is working on one link and refusing to work on another

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-router

I am designing the login sequence of my app and there is a page in which I have to let the user choose wether to sign up or sign in. Supposed to be very basic.

2 functions respond to the two different buttons and I put a console.log in each function to test and both log to the console successfully. Here is the code

`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signinup',
  templateUrl: './signinup.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signinup.page.scss'],
})
export class SigninupPage implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  onSignIn() {
    console.log('Sign in clicked');
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/sign-in');
  }

  onSignUp() {
    console.log('Sign up clicked');
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/account-type');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(
      'I have the Country saved as ' + this.authService.locale.country
    );
    console.log(
      'I have the Language saved as ' + this.authService.locale.language
    );
  }
}
```

`

The sign up page loads alright, but the sign in page does not load at all.

Let me also attach the code of the Sign in page so that you can take a look as well.

`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.page.scss'],
})
export class SignInPage implements OnInit {
  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth, public router: Router) {}

  async onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    const { email, password, keepLoggedIn } = form.value;
    console.log(email, password, keepLoggedIn);
    await this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
  }

  googleLogin() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

`

I just now noticed that the sign in page does not load even when I try to pull it up manually by entering the url. Please I would appreciate your help.

I tried to route to different pages using the navigateByUrl function and one loads but another will not load. I cannot find any syntax error in the code.

Comment: Can you provide your router module / routes?

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance!
I later on realized the source of my problem. It was the new modifications on AngularFireAuth, so every page I had imported it on and declared it in the constructor was not displaying.